# Error in xml and want to read each node from xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-parsing

below is myxml string,can someone tell me what is wrong in this xml,besides this when i am trying to load and readxml it is giving me error Invalid character string since my UpgradeDBTemplate node contains "" and curly braces {} how to solve this ?

```
private string DBConfiguration =
                             @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
                             <ArrayOfDB xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
                                      <Database name=""mysql""> 
                                              <UpgradeScriptPath>/Data/upgradescript.xml.config</UpgradeScriptPath>
                                              <DBBinPath>mysql</DBBinPath>
                                              <UpgradeDBTemplate>""{0}"" -h{2} -uroot -p{1} < upgrade_db.txt </UpgradeDBTemplate>
                                      </Database>
                                      <Database name=""mssql""> 
                                              <UpgradeScriptPath> </UpgradeScriptPath>
                                              <DBBinPath>SQLCMD</DBBinPath>
                                              <UpgradeDBTemplate>""{0}"" -S {2} -U sa -p{1} -i upgrade_db.txt</UpgradeDBTemplate>
                                      </Database>
                             </ArrayOfDB >
                             ";
```

Comment: Please show us the code that fails, as well as just the string.

Comment: `< upgrade_db.txt ` is not valid xml "how to solve this ?" start with transforming '< upgrade_db.txt ' to '&lt; upgrade_db.txt '

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
/// Replaces invalid XML characters in a string with their valid XML equivalent.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="xmlString">The XML string.</param>
/// <returns>Valid Xml</returns>
public static string ReplaceInvalidXml(string xmlString)
{
    return System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(xmlString);
}
```